# non-standard compilation shortcuts in vscode + latex-workshop

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I set up the latex-workshop extension in vscode to run only a single `pdflatex` on each save instead of the whole `latexmk`, to make it faster. Now I want to bind `latexmk` to a keyboard shortcut. I tried

```
    {
        "key": "f9",
        "command": "latex-workshop.latexmk",
        "when": "editorLangId == latex"
    },
```

in `keybindings.json`, but that only gives a popup saying `command 'latex-workshop.latexmk' not found` when pressing `f9`.

What do I have to put under `command`?

Comment: use the keybinding dialog to find the command by search of the string used in the Command Palette, maybe `latex-workshop.build`

Comment: @rivV8 the keybindings dialog allows only one build-keybinding, which can be set to either pdflatex or latexmk. However, I want to have different keybindings for both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After raising the question as an issue on github, it was pointed out to me that it had already been answered [here](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/2577#issuecomment-797383801).

Here's what I put in `keybindings.json` do make it work:

```
    {
        "key": "f9",
        "command": "latex-workshop.recipes",
        "args": "latexmk ",
        "when": "editorLangId == latex"
    },
```